# Opening terminal from command line, starting bash and got to the same location where the original terminal was

Tags: applescript, mojave, bash

For example, I have a terminal (running /bin/bash) opened at a certain folder. Now what I want is when I type `trm` on the terminal, it will open another terminal at the same location where the first terminal was.

In my `.bash_aliases` I am doing like this --

```
_openTerminal()
{
    pdir=$(pwd)
    /usr/bin/osascript << EOF
        set pwd_ashell to do shell script "echo '$pdir'" 
        tell application "Terminal" 
            do script "/bin/bash && cd \"$pwd_ashell\""
        end tell
EOF
}
```

and setting alias as:

```
alias trm='_openTerminal'
```

It opens a terminal but always ends up in the `$HOME` folder.

Comment: You can open a new tab with command-T and then drag the tab out of the window if you need a separate window.

Comment: @lhf command-T opens a new tab in `$HOME`

Comment: Are you sure? Open a Terminal window, do `cd /tmp`, and then command-T. You should have two tabs in `/tmp`.It works for me in El Capitan.